# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djongo'

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Django project which ironically uses the `djongo` python package. I installed the requirements file for the project which includes `djongo` but I still get:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djongo'
```

How can I get the `djongo` package installed locally?

Answer (score 2):

Despite `djongo` being in the requirements file, I had to do an explicit `pip3 install djongo` which resolved the issue for me.